# category subcategory drf django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

i have this category and subcategory models:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
      name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
      slug = models.SlugField()   
      parent = TreeForeignKey('self',blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index = True)


     class MPTTMeta:
           unique_together = ('slug', 'parent') 
           verbose_name_plural = "categories"
           order_insertion_by = ['name']

    def __str__(self):  
        full_path = [self.name]       
        k = self.parent       
        while k is not None:
              full_path.append(k.name)
               k = k.parent
        return ' -> '.join(full_path[::-1])
```

serializers.py:

```
class SubCategroySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('id', 'name','slug', 'children')
```

## category Listing Api

```
class CategorySerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      children = SubCategroySerializer(many=True, required=False)
      class Meta:
            model = Category
            fields = ('id','name','slug','children')
```

currently its working but i want to show subcategory inside category only not as a main category as you can see subcategory are listed inside main category and with maincategory also
[image]

expected result:

```
   [
   {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Animals & Wildlife",
        "slug": "animals_wildlife",
        "children": []
   },
   {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "main cat",
        "slug": "mai_cat",
        "children": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "sub_cat",
            "slug": "submaincat",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
   },

{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "maincat2",
    "slug": "maincat2",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "submaincat2",
            "slug": "submaincat2",
            "children": []
        }
    ]
},

{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "maincat3",
    "slug": "maincat3",
    "children": []
}
]
```

Comment: Did not understand why you used foreignkey inside subcategory model.

Comment: consider no subcategory model

Comment: What is your expected result looks like ?

Comment: see the edits...